# Prevent files and folders from certain directories from being deleted

Tags: c#, delete-file

I have a simple function that deletes every file and folder in a target directory. I want to blacklist some directories so that this delete function will not perform the deletion on any file or folder inside any of these directories. Also, it should't delete sub-directories in this directory.

I used a list to represent the blacklisted directories:

```
private string[] blacklistedFolders =
 {
    "C:/Program Files",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)",
    "C:/ProgramData",
    "C:/Users",
    "C:/Windows"
};
```

The code that deletes items in a directory:

```
bool IsBacklisted(string targetDir)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < blacklistedFolders.Length; i++)
    {
        string bList = blacklistedFolders[i];

        //Check if the targetDir contains the target directory
        if (bList.Contains(targetDir))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public void EmptyDirectory(string targetDir)
{
    //Exit if path is blacklisted
    if (IsBacklisted(targetDir))
        return;

    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(targetDir);

    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in dInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        fileInfo.Delete();
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in dInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        dirInfo.Delete(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'am worried that this blacklisted part of the code might fail resulting to the files and folders from the blacklisted directory being deleted. Maybe the blacklist check may not match on *different platforms* due to the presence of `"/"` or `"\"` at the end or middle of the path or other scenarios I may have missed.

Is there a built-in `System.IO` function or a better way to do this check other that the `String.Contains` function I am currently using to check for blacklisted directories?

Comment: Are those directories just example directories, or are do they really reflect at least some of the directories that you want excluded? The reason I ask is that you have a bigger problem if you're deleting all files underneath the drive where you'd need to exclude those directories. Those directories aren't an exhaustive list of system and system-needed directories; and even if you get that list there's no guarantee it'll be accurate tomorrow. This is a good recipe to mess up your Windows or other people's Windows installations.

Comment: They are just example directories and not the actual ones that will be used. Remember that I am not deleting the directory but every files and folders in it. The directory itself stays.

Comment: You could use `StartsWith` rather than `Contains`, and use the case insensitive overload. Not sure why the examples use `/` for the directory separator on paths which look like Windows folder names: I'd expect them to have \ (just put `@` before the `"` to stop the compiler misunderstanding the backslashes).

Comment: I realize that, but losing the contents of a system-needed directory is going to be just as devastating. I'd consider requiring that anything being deleted be whitelisted or explicitly included -- at least a base directory.

Comment: @Richardissimo Case insensitive check... That's really a good idea.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, you need to exclude cases where the directory being removed is an exact match (case insensitively) of a blacklisted folder, or it StartsWith(ci) a blacklisted folder plus a directory separator character (otherwise you'll prevent deletion of "C:/Userstone", which is not on the blacklist).

Comment: And I'm sure you know there's `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` which should help you write code which is platform agnostic in terms of the slashes, and things like `Path.Combine("C:", "Program Files")` might help when putting the blacklist values together agnostically, although that doesn't quite do what you might hope, so for the very first parameter you'll need to manually add the DirectorySeparatorChar suffix. (Maybe put that drive and separator in a variable and reuse it.) Note: I'm using agnostic in the sense that different platforms would need different compilations.

Comment: But even / is valid. For example windows will accept a path of "c:\my\path/to/another\folder" also "c:\this\is\.\also\..\..\valid" - - you need to normalize directory names first (use Path.GetFullPath), perform case-insensitive checks and perhaps always add (or trim) the trailing path separators. But that only gets you so far. What about junction points--They're real too! Or paths using long-file name format "\\?\c:\mydir\“ which is equivalent to "c:\mydir" yet won't get translated as such by GetFullPath (at least I think). Use whitelists, not blacklists and normalize the best you can.

Comment: There's also `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar`. You could probably make use of the `Uri.IsBaseOf` method after adding trailing slashes to the list of folder names. This is as at least smart enough to handle directory traversal attacks and take into account alternate path separators. I'm not sure how it handles case sensitivity (I assume insensitive) and it's still not going to help with some edge cases